# Normals seem to be the wrong way around

Tags: opengl, 3d, shader, fragment-shader, lighting

I have the feeling that my normals are the wrong way around, however how can I confirm that it is the issue and how would I fix it?

What I am visually experiencing is that I have a big ground plane at `y = -10` (y being the up/down axis), and having some small terrain from `(0, y, 0)` to `(4, y, 4)` with `0 <= y <= 5` roughly.

Then I have a light that emits ambient and diffuse light from `(0.0, 7.5, 0.0)`.
When I look from above the terrain onto the terrain, I only see ambient.
When I look from below the terrain onto the terrain, then I start to see the diffuse light.

The responsible shaders for this are:

`terrain.vs.glsl`

```
#version 440 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

layout(location = 0) uniform mat4 model_matrix;
layout(location = 1) uniform mat4 view_matrix;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = view_matrix * model_matrix * position;
}
```

`terrain.tcs.glsl`

```
#version 440 core

layout(vertices = 16) out;

void main(void) {
    uint id = gl_InvocationID;

    if (id == 0) {
        gl_TessLevelInner[0] = 32.0;
        gl_TessLevelInner[1] = 32.0;

        gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = 32.0;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = 32.0;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = 32.0;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[3] = 32.0;
    }

    gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[id].gl_Position;
}
```

`terrain.tes.glsl`

```
#version 440 core

layout(quads, equal_spacing, cw) in;

layout(location = 0) uniform mat4 model_matrix;
layout(location = 1) uniform mat4 view_matrix;
layout(location = 2) uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

out TES_OUT {
    vec3 N;
    vec3 L;
    vec3 V;
} tes_out;

uniform vec3 light_pos = vec3(0.0, 7.5, 0.0);

vec4 quadratic_bezier(vec4 A, vec4 B, vec4 C, float t) {
    vec4 D = mix(A, B, t);
    vec4 E = mix(B, C, t);

    return mix(D, E, t);
}

vec4 cubic_bezier(vec4 A, vec4 B, vec4 C, vec4 D, float t) {
    vec4 E = mix(A, B, t);
    vec4 F = mix(B, C, t);
    vec4 G = mix(C, D, t);

    return quadratic_bezier(E, F, G, t);
}

vec4 evaluate_patch(vec2 at) {
    vec4 P[4];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        P[i] = cubic_bezier(gl_in[i].gl_Position, gl_in[i + 4].gl_Position, gl_in[i + 8].gl_Position, gl_in[i + 12].gl_Position, at.y);
    }

    return cubic_bezier(P[0], P[1], P[2], P[3], at.x);
}

const float epsilon = 0.001;

void main(void) {
    vec4 p1 = evaluate_patch(gl_TessCoord.xy);
    vec4 p2 = evaluate_patch(gl_TessCoord.xy + vec2(0.0, epsilon));
    vec4 p3 = evaluate_patch(gl_TessCoord.xy + vec2(epsilon, 0.0));

    vec3 v1 = normalize(p2.xyz - p1.xyz);
    vec3 v2 = normalize(p3.xyz - p1.xyz);

    //normal
    tes_out.N = cross(v1, v2);

    //light vector
    tes_out.L = light_pos - p1.xyz;

    //view vector
    tes_out.V = -p1.xyz;

    gl_Position = proj_matrix * p1;
}
```

`terrain.fs.glsl`

```
#version 440 core

out vec4 color;

in TES_OUT {
    vec3 N;
    vec3 L;
    vec3 V;
} fs_in;

uniform vec3 ambient = vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
uniform vec3 diffuse_albedo = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

void main(void) {
    //normalize
    vec3 N = normalize(fs_in.N);
    vec3 L = normalize(fs_in.L);
    vec3 V = normalize(fs_in.V);

    //calculate R
    vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);

    //calculate diffuse
    vec3 diffuse = max(dot(N, L), 0.0) * diffuse_albedo;

    //write color
    color = vec4(ambient + diffuse, 1.0);
}
```

Could anyone give me some hints?

**Update**: Another odd thing I have noticed is that I am defining `light_pos` in plain coordinates. Shouldn't I apply the `view_matrix` on them?

Comment: How are you building your objects? [`glFrontFace()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml) will let you choose the winding order of your polygons. You can switch between clockwise and counter-clockwise with it.

Comment: @user1118321 Reversing `cross(v1, v2)` to `cross(v2, v1)` seems to have fixed it.

Comment: The light position does not need to be defined in view space, typically it is in world-space and you will use it to compute a direction vector and then toss it. This can either be done by transforming the surface point into world-space or the light position into view-space, or even in tangent-space. The coordinate space you choose will generally depend on the space your normals are in.

Comment: Having said that, after looking at your TES, `light_pos` should be defined in view-space to produce a correct direction vector because `p1` appears to be in view-space.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Another thing I'm concerned about is that the shading also works below a surface (if the light is above that surface), how would I fix that and which problem am I experiencing?